# How do I extract current process CPU usage by path/command and print it to the console

Tags: command, cpu, monitoring

I'd like to get current process CPU/memory usage% by process name/path and print it to the console. The command should output one number and not provide an ongoing data flow like `ps`.

`ps -p PID` doesn't work as:

1. I don't have the process number (I do have process path)
2. It doesn't print the current measurement once to the console

So, for example, it should look something like:

```
$command -getCPU | grep processPath
```

Comment: How does `ps` create an "ongoing data flow"? I know what you mean, but on my systems `ps` returns a finite output.

Comment: To get the PID(s), use `pgrep -f /path/to/your/application`

Comment: To get cpu/mem for all PIDs, you can use `ps -p$(pgrep -d, -f /path/to/application) -o%cpu=,%mem=`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is `awk`,
You can use the following command to show the processor and memory usage of a process name.

`ps -C "PROCEES_NAME" -o %cpu,%mem,cmd`

result:

```
%CPU %MEM CMD
 0.0  0.2 /usr/bin/python3 completion.py
 0.0  0.1 /usr/bin/python3 lib/python/jedi/evaluate/compiled/subprocess/__main__.py lib/python
```

Then you can use awk to remove the first line:

`ps -C python3 -o %cpu,%mem,cmd | awk 'FNR > 1'`

result:

```
 0.0  0.2 /usr/bin/python3 completion.py
 0.0  0.1 /usr/bin/python3 lib/python/jedi/evaluate/compiled/subprocess/__main__.py lib/python
```

And if you want get only numbers of usage and skip the other outputs, you can use following command:

`ps -C "python3" -o %cpu,%mem,cmd | awk 'FNR > 1 {print $1,$2}'`

result:

```
0.0 0.2
0.0 0.1
```

`$1` is first row and `$2` is second row you can remove them if you want.

Remember using process_name is a bad idea, using PID is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i confused between top and ps. 
I was able to get what I wanted using the following command:

```
$ps aux | grep <processName> | awk '{print $3}'
```

Row number 3 is the current CPU percentage.

Comment: That's a bad idea, because grep will catch every string similar to your <processName>, don't use this line of command in your product.